# iOS5 Saving images to custom folder, ALAssetsLibrary fail

Tags: ios5, save, alassetslibrary

**<><>  ----
Aalok has answered this question, I'm just waiting for him to write it up so I can chose that as the correct answer.  Until then, along with making the changes he describes below I had to call -- self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]; -- before every attempt to save my image.  As a precaution I also stopped the AVSession running until after the save, when is was restarted (using [session stopRunning]; and [session startRunning];
----- <><>**

**<><> ----- EDIT 2:  You do not need to stop and restart the AV session, tested this thoroughly and it's working perfectly. ----- <><>**

**<><> ----- EDIT 3: after testing this on my device thoroughly, and it working perfectly, the code is not working once it's been through the review process and put on the store.  Two identical devices (2x iPhone 4) running the same OS, one using my dev build, one off the app sotre, the ap store version still has the bug.  Giving up with this for now ----- <><>**

I'm using the category in this link to try to save to a custom folder:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

Now it works some of the time, but not all.  In the comments it's been suggested that the following code will detect if the group properties are nil:

```
    if ([group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyURL] == nil)
{
NSLog(@”group properties are nil!”);
} else {
[group addAsset:asset];
}
```

Which I have, and it does detect if the properties are nil.  So all good.  What I'm struggling with is at that point setting the properties and saving the images.  I'm guessing that at this point we can manually set the albumName and save the image, which I've tried, but the error still occurs.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: This is fine if you stays on the same view but if you are navigate to other view through the push navigation you must have to stop session otherwise it gives you error exactly at third time of taking image and navigating to the next view and try to save the image

Comment: OK, thanks for that.  On my app I remove any ability to do anything while this is taking place so it's not a problem, but on a future version I'll take this into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have facing the same problem with this same .h and .m file but find one solution for this after working on it for 2 to 3 days and the solution is very simple what I have to change is in .m file in

`-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock`

and in

`-(void)addAssetURL:(NSURL*)assetURL toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock`

methods i just add this before calling the inside methods

```
//THE CHANGE dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{ //
[self writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) 
    {
        //error handling
        if (error!=nil) 
        {
            completionBlock(error);
            return;
        }
        //add the asset to the custom photo album
        [self addAssetURL: assetURL toAlbum:albumName withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
    }];
//THE CHANGE }); //
```

AND Same for the other one

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT**

In second method I add a line below every `completionBlock(nil);` line

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSaveSuccess object:nil];
```

And I use this notification to make sure that image is saved in album too. Till that time I Shows `UIActivityIndicator` with some text message and after successfully saved image one popup message is shown indicated that image is saved in album with album name. And while this time the UI is unresponsive i.e. user can't do any thing other then pressing home button of device :) ;)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: If is there any problem please let me know as this solve the described problem for me :)

Comment: In the second function, does your change go above or below the __block BOOL albumWasFound = NO; line?  I'm not at home until very late tonight to try this.  Thanks for posting :)

Comment: Sadly this is not working for me, I save out three images and every time only three of the images save, the third always gives me a 'group properties are nil' issue and only saves to the camera roll.  I can sure code if that would help?

Comment: same here unfortunately ... :(

Comment: Actually it's random, so no change.  Apple really need to fix this.

Comment: i think you try to save images in quick succession and on every third or after third try it saves only in camera role. Right?

Comment: If so you need to provide some time to save the image in album and also in camera roll for that i have put some extra line of code too just see the edit

Comment: I already have a system which removes the ability to shoot more pictures until the last shot is saved, the button is physically removed from the view, and on completion of the final save, it's moved back.  The images always save to the camera roll, but randomly don't save to the custom folder, and there is no pattern at all. :/

Comment: Ohk got it but for me it always saves the image to both camera rolls and also to the album for each and every time. With which framework you take photos and try to save it?

Comment: I'm using AVFoundation to take the image, and then applying some OpenGLES filters to them before saving them out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13403/discussion-between-aalok-parikh-and-mrempty)